# Is it possible to publish an unpackaged Windows App SDK (WinUI 3) as self contained single file?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm pretty sure I have all the right flags and everything set according to Microsoft Docs, however the UI dlls are not being included in the single file exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. **Self-Contained** does not mean **One-Single-File**. It means that all the dependencies will be next to your EXE so you won't need to install runtimes to the target device.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it's possible either. I ended up just going with self contained non single file.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no way to produce a single EXE for net6.0 WinUI desktop app.

Fody does not work for this and while PublishSingleFile will indeed produce a single exe - it won't work, even with IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract. You will get DllNotFoundException exception at runtime. It is not resolved as of Windows App SDK 1.4.0.

This scenario is currently broken due to: https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/2597

Evidently in single-file scenarios the single file host is in one directory and everything else is extracted into another directory.

Perhaps a custom build task to copy all references theoretically would work?

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://github.com/Fody/Costura/

It's great for legacy .NET projects.  Newer frameworks have single-file executables as shown in their documentation

Comment: This isn't a legacy project though. It's .NET 6 with Windows App SDK 1.1

Answer (score 0):

Yes - with this (unpackaged / self-contained) command line:

`dotnet publish -f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:WindowsPackageType=None -p:SelfContained=true -p:WindowsAppSDKSelfContained=true`

Note: This requires Windows App SDK 1.1.0 or above.

Comment: Hmm, for me this not produces a single file exe. I did the same thing as you on CLI with the apropriate csproj XML settings. I can indeed create EITHER a single file exe (that „resources.something“ file asside), when not going Windows App SDK self-contained (means the SDK has to be installed on the tharget machine or the installer popup shows up), OR a Windows App SDK self-contained application, that is not a single file. Both (a single exe AND deploy SDK with/inside the exe) seems not possible. At least i could not achieve that goal.